# bad operand type for unary +: 'str' average test scores

Tags: python, function

I have to code this program for class and this is what I have so far. I run the code just fine but after inputting the scores the error message pops up.

```
def main(): 
    score_1_ = input('Enter score 1:')
    name_1_  = input('Enter name 1:')
    score_2_ = input('Enter score 2:')
    name_2_  = input('Enter name 2:')
    score_3_ = input('Enter score 3:')
    name_3_  = input('Enter name 3:')
    score_4_ = input('Enter score 4:')
    name_4_  = input('Enter name 4:')
    score_5_ = input('Enter score 5:')
    name_5_  = input('Enter name 5:')

    print('Name\t\tnumeric grade\tletter grade')
    print('-------------------------------------------')
    print(name_1_ + '\t\t', score_1_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_1_))
    print(name_2_ + '\t\t', score_2_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_2_))
    print(name_3_ + '\t\t', score_3_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_3_))
    print(name_4_ + '\t\t', score_4_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_4_))
    print(name_5_ + '\t\t', score_5_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_5_))
    print('------------------------------------------ ')

    print('Average score: ' )


    test_average = (score_1_ + score_2_ + score_3_ + score_4_ + score_5_) / 5.0

def calculate_average():
    average = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 / 5.0 )

def determine_grade():
    if score_1_ > 90:
        return 'A'
    elif score_2_ > 80:
        return 'B'
    elif score_3_ > 70:
        return 'C'
    elif score_4_ > 60:
        return 'D'
    else:
        score_5_ > 50
        return 'F'

main()
```

the issue I am having is this

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/m5.py", line 69, in 
        main()
      File "C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/m5.py", line 41, in main
        print(name_1_ + '\t\t', score_1_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_1_))
    TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: Look at the line `print(name_1_ + '\t\t', score_1_ , + '\t\t',determine_grade(score_1_))` closely.

Comment: Did you create another account or is this another person with the same assignment?

Comment: This is the same [assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454782/ask-user-for-names-scores-for-5-students-then-create-a-table-from-the-data?noredirect=1#comment54696312_33454782) that this person did.

Comment: This is my only account on stack overflow so another person.

Comment: The `, + '\t\t'` is causing the error. Either get rid of the `,` or the `+`. Do you understand _why_ that's causing the error?

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes: We often get a bunch of people working on the same assignment at the same time.

Comment: @BrandonBaichoo: have you ever heard what a loop is? D:

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Fair call; OTOH Brandon's teacher may not have covered such "advanced" techniques as loops and lists yet...

Comment: @PM 2Ring ok I did that and then I got the determine_grade() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I also looked up why that was and got the conclusion it was because it doesn't have self as a parameter.

Comment: There are several problems with your code, apart from the one you mentioned in your question. For a start, you need to convert the scores you read in from strings to integers at some stage so you can do arithmetic with them.

Comment: @PM2Ring oh OK. My class is to basic. All we do is use the myro bot and we have to use python 2.4.4 :(. I've self taught myself the entire course in probably 3 days. Right now the class is introducing  `if`` `else` statements.

Comment: couldn't i define it from the beginning such as [code]score1 = int(input('Enter score 1:')[/code] @PM2Ring

Comment: That `takes 0 positional arguments` is because you've defined the `determine_grade` function with `def determine_grade():`, which says it takes zero arguments, but you're calling it with one argument in `determine_grade(score_1_)`, etc.

Comment: Yes! You can do `score1 = int(input('Enter score 1:'))`. BTW, you use the backtick `\`` to put code into comments. Note that you should only put small amounts of code in comments, since there's no way to preserve indentation.

Comment: ok so I changed all but one to integers and the other to a float and now I am facing the 0 positional arguments problem but I am determined to figure it out! Thank you so far for all the help @PM2Ring

Comment: how would you recommend I tackle this one @PM2Ring...I tried doing `determine_grade(self):` but then I have to define it... is that the only thing I should do or do you have a better way of approaching it?

Comment: Could I possibly do something such as `determine_grade(score):`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is *your* homework I won't post a complete working program, but I'll help you fix a few things.

I recommend you remove the trailing underscore from your `score` and `name` variable names as they just make the code look cluttered. So your input codes should look like:

```
name_1 = input('Enter name 1:')
score_1 = float(input('Enter score 1:'))
```

If the scores are whole numbers then change that `float` to `int`. I've put the `name` before the `score` because I think it makes more sense that way.

The lines in the main printing section should look like this:

```
print(name_1, '\t\t', score_1, '\t\t', determine_grade(score_1))
```

You have code that correctly calculates the average but you never print it. You need:

```
test_average = (score_1 + score_2 + score_3 + score_4 + score_5) / 5.0
print('Average score:', test_average)
```

Get rid of that `calculate_average()` function, since you're not actually calling it. And it wouldn't work anyway because you haven't defined `s1`, `s2`, etc, anywhere, and it has the `)` in the wrong place.

Here's some code for determining grades. I've changed `>` to `>=` because generally you get an 'A' if your score is 90% or greater, a 'B' if your score is at least 80% and under 90%, etc.

```
def determine_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return 'A'
    elif score >= 80:
        return 'B'
    elif score >= 70:
        return 'C'
    elif score >= 60:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'
```

You now have everything you need to put together a working program.

Note that you could make your code a *lot* more compact if you used loops and lists.

Comment: Thank you for the help I figured everything else out!